# Google Search Console reports it is not crawling the hompage but it shows up in a site: search

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers, sitemap, duplicate-content

I recently retouched a corporate site for a client. They also have an ecommerce version of their site at another URL. I've submitted the sitemap and did a manual re-crawl request for the homepage of the corporate site. But I'm getting odd results in the search console.

Under url inspection, it says the homepage isn't crawled, but using 'site:' in google search shows it up. I know the homepage was recrawled because the google meta has updated but search console still says un-crawled. And for some reason, it has chosen to change the title of the homepage in the result but not the other pages.

Other pages at the url are crawled but search console says they aren't in the sitemap. Manual inspection shows they are. The last crawl date is also the same as last modified date on the sitemap. Copying the url directly from the sitemap into url inspector shows the same problem of page not being in sitemap. Both sitemap index and sitemap is submitted.

There are also no manual actions in search console. `robots.txt` is also fine.

Can a corporate site be too similar to an ecommerce site for the same company that it is refusing to crawl? I've even done `sameas` and included the ecommerce site in the schema.

They run two site because they have both a physical store and an online store selling the same thing, but the physical store also runs other operations and events.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the two sites being similar enough to be considered duplicates. Indexing doesn't happen instantly. You may just need to wait a few days.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! We do not allow new users to create links to their own or client sites. If anyone needs to view the site, they can simply review the edits to see the link. Cheers!!

Comment: Googles Search Console is very very slow to up update. As well, processing sitemaps does not coincide with crawling. This means that what you see in Search Console will not accurately reflect reality. This is especially true for pages found in the sitemap. Keep in mind that processing sitemaps is an auditing process that may restart from time to time. This means that the number of pages reported to be found may reduce and then increase from time to time. Cheers!!

Comment: @tshimkus @closetnoc would google think I'm trying to hijack someone else's business? It's ignoring the h1 tags, meta description, and schema description in search results (using `site:`) on a page I'm certain it just recrawled yesterday (I'm  checking everyday)

Answer (score 2):

Google was not always like that. After some recent updates this crawling and indexing issue is observed by many webmasters. The only thing you can do is create and submit your sitemap, do some manual crawl request and just wait...weeks...a month. Just wait.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have added the property to Google Search Console exactly as it is on the site.   If you create a URL prefix property (as opposed to a domain property), make you sure you create it with your canonical URLs.

I see that your redirect from `http` to `http` and also that you redirect to add the `www` with one of your sites.  However, the other site doesn't have a security certificate and uses `http`.

You may want to add all four variants for each site to Google Search Console just to make sure. Sometimes you may find that Google is trying to index a non-canonical URL on a different variant.

- `http://example.com/`
- `https://example.com/`
- `http://www.example.com/`
- `https://www.example.com/`

You could also verify your properties as "domain properties" which would allow you to inspect all the variant home page URLs under one property.

Comment: My money is on this. Doing a site: search indicates that the indexed home page is not https. Over time Google will pick up this is now redirecting and update the index.

Comment: I've added all 4 as URL properties and resubmitted sitemap and sitemap indexes on all of them. Is this common practice to add all variants of a URL prefix property to a domain property for retouched website or is this indications something goofy is going on with my settings?

Comment: Very common.  Nothing goofy going on.

Comment: There are two URLs https://cherrycrumble.com/ and  http://nitthyman.com/. Both of them were connected. After sometime I closed nitthyman url but still it open when I do google search (not directly).  Many urls are indexed and also opening category and product pages. I don't know how it's happening, may be it is virtually working.